# send image with retrofit 2 but server internal error in andorid?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, multipartform-data

can help me, i send image in retrofit with multipart but 500 Internal Server Error.

[This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8FQH.png)

[This End Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SskC1.png)

[This Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zphvd.png)

[This My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx3mL.png)

'override fun submitProduct(
namaProduct: String,
category: String,
filePath: Uri,
account: String,
hargaNormal: String,
hargaGrab: String,
hargaGojek: String,
stok: String
) {
val NAMAPRODUCT = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), namaProduct)
val CATEGORY = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), category)
val ACCOUNT = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), account)
val HARGANORMAL = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), hargaNormal)
val HARGAGRAB = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), hargaGrab)
val HARGAGOJEK = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), hargaGojek)
val STOK = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"), stok)

```
    var profileImageFile = File(filePath.path)
    var profileImageRequestBody = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("multipart/form_data"),
        profileImageFile
    )
    var profileImageParms = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
        "imageproduct",
        profileImageFile.name,
        profileImageRequestBody
    )
    view.showLoading()
    val disposable = HttpClient.getInstance().getApi()!!.addProduct(
        NAMAPRODUCT,
        CATEGORY,
        ACCOUNT,
        HARGANORMAL,
        HARGAGRAB,
        HARGAGOJEK,
        STOK,
        profileImageParms
    )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            {
                view.dismissLoading()

                if (it.meta?.status == 1) {
                    it.data?.let { it1 ->
                        view.onSubmitSucces(
                            it1,
                            it.meta?.message.toString()
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    it.meta?.message?.let { it1 -> view.onSubmitFailed(it1) }
                }
            },
            {
                view.dismissLoading()
                view.onSubmitFailed(it.message.toString())
            }
        )
    mCompositeDisposable!!.add(disposable)
}'
```

Comment: Please post the code and logs as text and not as images, as [explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5251245)

Comment: I have added on question

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on server. The problem is with the server code i.e backend and not with your frontend.

Comment: i am still confused if i test on postman it works, but when i send in my emulator it gives me 500 server internal error.

Comment: You should try looking at the logs in your backend. You might find something. It is not able to handle the request due to some reason.

Comment: i checked in my log,i only find this '2021-05-06T09:13:22.474083+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/insertproduct 500 5087.484 ms - 32'